# ¿Como puedo convertir en entero más de un valor en c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

quiero saber como le hago para lograr eso con esta forma en la que tengo mi codigo, es para la cedula y el telefono con los que trabajo en c# con sql server:

```
private void btnInsertar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cl.Clienteregistrado(Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text)) == 0)
            {

            MessageBox.Show(cl.insertar1(Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text),txtcedula.Text, txtnombre.Text, txtdireccion.Text, txtTelefono.Text));
            cl.Cargarpantallaclientes(pantallaclientes);
            txtid.Text = "";
            txtcedula.Text = "";
            txtnombre.Text = "";
            txtdireccion.Text = "";
            txtTelefono.Text = "";
```

Aquí la clase que hace referencia a clienteregistrado

```
public int Clienteregistrado(int id)
        {
            int contador = 0;
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select  * from CLIENTES where id=" + id + "", cn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    contador++;
                }
                dr.Close();

            }






            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo consultar: " + ex.ToString());



            }
            return contador;
```

Comment: Hola, NO queda claro cuál es tu duda se ve que usas Convert.ToInt32, ¿qué problema tienes?

Comment: Que quiero convertir en int lo que vendría siendo la cedula y el telefono, solo puedo hacerlo con una sola cosa y es el id. pero ya no se como convertir la cedula y el telefono en enteros.

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(txtCedula) y Convert.ToInt32(txtTelefono)? sólo le estás aplicando el convert a una caja de texto